# Get wrong Date from parsing time string by SimpleDateFormat. (1 hour offset) [Android/Java]

Tags: java, android, timezone, locale, simpledateformat

First of all, I would like to make clear that it is not daylight saving issue.

Second, after trying hard, it seems related to the locale used in SimpleDateFormat.

Third, it seems only to occur with PST/PDT timezone. UTC is ok.

---

Here is the test code.

Use US and ENGLISH locale to parse the same Date.

```
    try {
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat US_format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
        SimpleDateFormat EN_format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);

        US_format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")); //Set PST Timezone
        String US_str =  US_format.format(date);
        Log.i("DEBUG", "US_str: " + US_str);
        Log.i("DEBUG", "US_str: " + US_format.format(US_format.parse(US_str)));

        EN_format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")); //Set PST Timezone
        String EN_str =  EN_format.format(date);
        Log.i("DEBUG", "EN_str: " + EN_str);
        Log.i("DEBUG", "EN_str: " + EN_format.format(EN_format.parse(EN_str)));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.i("DEBUG", "Parsing Error");
    }
```

The result is

> 02-26 19:42:42.863 I/DEBUG﹕ US_str: Feb 26 19:42:42 PST
>
> 02-26 19:42:42.865 I/DEBUG﹕ US_str: Feb 26 ***18:42:42*** PST
>
> 02-26 19:42:42.865 I/DEBUG﹕ EN_str: Feb 26 19:42:42 PST
>
> 02-26 19:42:42.866 I/DEBUG﹕ EN_str: Feb 26 19:42:42 PST

Is it a bug?
Why is there a one-hour difference in Locate.US?

====================================

Update:
It seems only to happen on Android 5.0 device.
Other environments seems ok.

Posted a bug on Android issue tracker. (Issue [158265](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=158265&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars))

Comment: Still not fixed ? 

I'm in Germany, 17 April 2015 at 09:26.
Calling
 String currentDateandTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
returns
2015-04-16 16:22:49 (wrong day and wrong time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Android issue Issue [158265](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=158265).

The Google engineer replied the answer as below.

> The Nexus 5 appears to not be able to update the RTC clock hardware. When the user (or the OS) changes the clock it is not persisted to the device hardware permanently. The next time the device reboots it reads the value from the RTC hardware and sets it into the system clock. In my case, two devices I tried had the RTC set to 1971.
>
> The system clock (what the user sees) is initially set from the RTC but is independent. If the user has set the device to sync the system clock from a network source then by the time the device has finished booting the system clock will be set correctly. Without the ability to write back to it the RTC will still be wrong.
>
> Unfortunately, the information used for parsing zone information like PST is cached during boot in the zygote process while the clock is still wrong. In my case it is looking at the timezone names as they were in 1971, but then using the offset information for today. This means that we incorrectly select Dawson_Creek as a proxy for PST, but the offset for Dawson_Creek *today* is actually that for MST/MDT.
>
> The reason of seeing issues with some locales and not others is that the zygote cache contains at most 3 entries after boot:
>
> 1) Locale.ROOT 2) Locale.US 3)
>
> Using ENGLISH (en) is recognized as different locale than US (en_US)
>   so it does not use the data cached during boot, and so the current
>   (correct) system clock time is used.

In short, this issue is supposed only to occur on an Android device with a *BAD* RTC hardware.

The zygote process generates a timezone cache in the beginning of boot up sequence with the *BAD* time. So timezone parsing with the default Locale.US is wrong.

The result of parsing with a Locale different from the default is correct because it generates the timezone data with the time which has already been corrected/synced with the network time.

To avoid the issue, just use the locale other than the default to parse the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

I think error might be from Logger.It was not related to locale .

```
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat US_format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
    SimpleDateFormat EN_format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);

    String US_str =  US_format.format(date);
    System.out.println( "US_str: " + US_str);
    System.out.println( "US_str: " + US_format.format(US_format.parse(US_str)));

    String EN_str =  EN_format.format(date);
    System.out.println( "EN_str: " + EN_str);
    System.out.println( "EN_str: " + EN_format.format(EN_format.parse(EN_str)));
```

This is the output obtained in my pc:

US_str: Feb 27 12:18:26 IST

US_str: Feb 27 12:18:26 IST

EN_str: Feb 27 12:18:26 IST

EN_str: Feb 27 12:18:26 IST

Hope this helps u.

Comment: I tried your code, but got the same result in my device.

Comment: Would you please help to use PST/PDT timezone?
I think the issue is related to the timezone and locale.